# VUEjs 3 Warning: Maximum recursive updates exceeded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

currently I am facing the problem that Vue issues a warning:
"Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function."

I can't figure out where the error should be.
I iterate over 2 loops and then want to give a counter value to the component inside, which is then passed on and then interpreted by modulus to CSS classes in 3rd level.
Unfortunately I have to do it this way, because the created components are parts of a dynamically created CSS grid. I would like to provide virtually every row, so all cells at the same height with a uniform "even/odd" class.

Here is the vue-component that creates this increment:

```
<template>
    <template v-for="(project, p) in projects" :key="project.id">
        <template v-for="(component, c) in project.components" :key="component.id">
            <grid-swim-lane
                :project="project"
                :component="component"
                :grid-row-even-odd-count="evenOddCount++"
            />
        </template>
    </template>
</template>

<script>
import GridSwimLane from "./GridSwimLane";
import {mapGetters} from "vuex";

export default {
    components: { GridSwimLane },
    data() {
        return {
            evenOddCount: -1
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters('projects', { projects: 'getAllProjects' })
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

This increment value is generated and successfully passed through to the last component despite the warning. But how can I make it work without the warning?
I have already tried a few things. But I can't get any further.

I can't do this with CSS selectors, because I want to work with fixed classes.

Thanks in advance for your tips.

Comment: This: `"evenOddCount++"` looks like it causes this. You cannot change the app state during rendering. Just use the index instead.

Comment: you can try this: replace `eventOddCount++` on `p + c`, it should have the same effect

Comment: @TinaGordienko_Drog I don't think that'll work because component 1 in project 2 will have the same count as component 2 in project 1. The proper solution is to assign the count variable to the projects in the state.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, youŕe right. Exactly thereś my problem. But how to solve?
"The proper solution is to assign the count variable to the projects in the state." --> I will think about this solution. Thanx

Comment: @TinaGordienko_Drog No, I tried. There are lines that get the same class. So there are "overlaps" here.

Comment: If all projects have the same number of components you can use `p * project.components.length + c`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, the each grid-swim-lane component's `this.$.uid` value is not sequential, but in sequence even and odd :-)

So i use this value to determine the 'even' and 'odd' css-class:

```
<template>

    <!-- ------------------ BEGIN LEFT SIDE BAR ------------------ -->

    <grid-swim-lane-info
        :grid-row-even-odd-count="gridRowEvenOddCount"
    />

    <!-- ------------------ BEGIN RELEASES ------------------- -->

    <grid-swim-lane-releases
        :grid-row-even-odd-count="gridRowEvenOddCount"
    />

</template>

<script>
import GridSwimLaneInfo from "./GridSwimLaneInfo";
import GridSwimLaneReleases from "./GridSwimLaneReleases";

export default {
    components: {
        GridSwimLaneInfo, GridSwimLaneReleases
    },
    props: {
        component:   { type: Object, default: { id: 0, name: 'no-component'} }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            gridRowEvenOddCount: 0
        }
    }
    mounted() {
        this.gridRowEvenOddCount = this.$.uid;
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```